# referenence request: yet another tangent half-angle formula

Tags: reference-request, trigonometry

It is widely known that
$$
\frac{\sin\alpha+\sin\beta}{\cos\alpha+\cos\beta} = \tan\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}.
$$

I'm wondering if the following is "known" in the sense of being in published sources?

Suppose $\alpha,\beta,\gamma\in(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$.
$$
\text{If }\frac{\sin\alpha\sin\beta}{\cos\alpha+\cos\beta} = \tan\gamma,\text{ then }\tan\frac\gamma2 = \tan\frac\alpha2\cdot\tan\frac\beta2.
$$

Comment: Maybe I need to say "If $\dfrac{\sin\alpha\sin\beta}{\cos\alpha+\cos\beta} = \tan\gamma$ and $-\pi/2<\alpha, \beta,\gamma<\pi/2$", and then do something piecewise for the other half of the circle.

Comment: Empirical evidence confirms my comment above.

Comment: I should have interchanged the "if" and the "then"?  Then the proposition would be true without the extra condition that the angles are between $\pm\pi/2$.